# EntityFieldQuery order by title

Tags: database

I'm getting an error when using this entity field query, the error says that that the field title cannot be found but I'm only querying the basic node table.

```
$product_query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')->entityCondition('bundle', 'product')->fieldCondition('field_line', 'tid', $selected)->fieldOrderBy('title', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The node title is a *property*, not a field:

```
$product_query 
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'product')
  ->fieldCondition('field_line', 'tid', $selected)
  ->propertyOrderBy('title', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Unless you're using [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) and the [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module.  In that case, to get the localized title, you should use:

`->fieldOrderBy('title_field', 'value', 'ASC')`

Answer (score 0):

```
                $queryst = new EntityFieldQuery();
                $queryst->entityCondition('entity_type','node');
                $queryst->propertyCondition('status', 1);   
                //$queryst->propertyOrderBy('nid','DESC');
                $queryst->fieldOrderBy('field_sort_order', 'value', 'ASC');
                $queryst->entityCondition('bundle','bill_status'); 
                $result_st = $queryst->execute();
```